# Can we show lockscreen media controls without playing a media on the phone?

Tags: ios, cocoa, mpnowplayinginfocenter, mpremotecommandcenter

I'm trying to develop an app which shows lockscreen media controls (`MPRemoteCommandCenter` and `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`).
The tricky part is that I'm not playing a media on the phone but on a remote server (like **Google cast**).

I managed to do it by playing a silent audio file on the phone which shows the lockscreen controls but it doesn't feel like a good solution (unnecessary battery drain).

Is it possible to show these controls without playing anything on the phone ?

[image]

Comment: Same problem with google cast... Did you solve?

Comment: I didn't, if you find anything please let me know ;)

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for the same problem.
@Salah, In your screen shot there is no Airplay Icon, how did you manage to hide it? Can we hide these player controls? like "Airplay", "Volume Bar"?

Comment: @ShivaReddy I think the AirPlay icon autohides if there are no airplay capable device nearby, which was the case. I didn't try to hide other controls but I think you can't.